# How to force css paragraph in a text fetched by a php function?

Tags: php, html, mysql, magento

In order to get the product description in some places in the Magento 1.7.0.2
I am using the `<?php echo $_product->getDescription() ?>`

The problem is that **I want to split the fetched text into 2 or more paragraphs**.

Is that possible to to do this ? 
Do I have to include in the mysql somes `<p>` or some `<span>` inside the text?

I don t really know how to approach it...

Does anyone has any suggestion ?

Comment: question is related to http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could use **wordwrap()**, it wraps a string into a given number of characters *without break any word (optional parameter to do it)*, and it let you choose the break parameter. In this example it's spliting the string into paragraphs of 80 characters lenght each:

```
echo wordwrap($_product->getDescription, 80, "<br />\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

use substr() to divide the string into two parts.
then echo those seperately. In between you can use